# Encrypt AES in Visual Basic then Decrypt AES in javascript - Server to client

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am looking for a good and simple way to encrypt a value on a visual basic web method and then when I fetch the cyphertext on javascript, to decrypt this.

I believe my options for decryption on javascript are CryptoJS
I also found a [Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on excryption in visual basic using AES.

My questions are:

- How can I use CryptoJS or any better method to decrypt the server ciphertext response
- Am I going about this the right way? Are there any simpler methods?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use CryptoJS or any better method to decrypt the server ciphertext response?

By doing the reverse operation to the one you are doing on the server.

> Am I going about this the right way? Are there any simpler methods?

Doing crypto in the browser is almost never a good idea, unless it is TLS - how can the server trust the client? Is there a simpler way? The ceasar cipher is probably simpler as you don't have to encode the result - it's of course also completely unsafe.